# jQuery Validation plugin error messages at END of list for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, custom-errors

I am using the [Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) for jQuery and it works wonders. Except when I have a group of checkboxes...the error messages will display right after the first box...like so[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/8986/errormessaged.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/8986/errormessaged.png)

and that is after I have created a "hidden" checkbox at the beginning of the group. Is there anyway i can make it display after the LAST checkbox? Is this a javascript thing? or a css?

Thanks!
Ian McCullough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the errorPlacement argument to the validator (see the [example on this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)).